# Evaluate in Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate, evaluation

I have a problems with Evaluate in Manipulate. Here is the code

```
fls = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"};
vars = Table[Symbol["$x" <> ToString@i], {i, fls // Length}];
n = 4;

Manipulate[
  Evaluate@{fls, vars}, 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[{{vars[[i]], 1, fls[[i]]}, Range[n]}, {i, 1, vars // Length}]]
]

Manipulate[
   Last /@ Normal@GroupBy[Thread[Evaluate@{fls, vars}], Last -> First],
 Evaluate[Sequence @@Table[{{vars[[i]], 1, fls[[i]]}, Range[n]}, {i, 1, vars // Length}]]
]
```

In the first Manipulate evaluation works, but in the second do not and I do not understand why. Second Manipulate should return {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"}} after execution of this code in it

```
Last /@ Normal@ GroupBy[Thread[{fls, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}], Last -> First]
```

while it returns {{"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {"e"}, {"f"}, {"g"}}. This happens because Evaluate does not work as I suppose.

Comment: It seems the `Thread` introduces the additional braces. Can't you simply use `Flatten`? As in `Flatten[Last /@ Normal@ GroupBy ...`.

Comment: No I cannot... I need Thread.

Comment: I meant this `Flatten[Last /@ Normal@ GroupBy[Thread[{fls, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}], Last -> First]]`.

Comment: It is not what I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbols in `vars` (in the body of the second `Manipulate`) are not the same as the localized `vars` in the `Evaluate[Sequence[..]]` declaration.  The `Evaluate@..` in the body is pretty much a no-op, since it does not appear at the top level (in a function whose arguments are held, which would have to be `Manipulate` to get them localized properly).

One workaround:

```
Manipulate[
   Last /@ 
    Normal@GroupBy[foo = Thread[Evaluate@{fls, #}], Last -> First], 
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ 
     Table[{{vars[[i]], 1, fls[[i]]}, Range[n]}, {i, 1, 
       vars // Length}]]] &@vars
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]